# ansible filter with json_query

Tags: ansible, jinja2, jmespath

I write this:

```
- name: test for seed
  debug:
    var: hostvars|json_query("*.ansible_host")
```

And it prints every host. But this does not filter hosts:

```
- name: test for seed
  debug:
    var: hostvars|json_query("*[?ansible_host=='192.168.56.101']")
```

It just prints an empty list, while I'm sure this host exists. This is the relevant inventory line:

```
[build-servers]
build-server ansible_host=192.168.56.101
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should filter resulting list, not original hash: `* | [?ansible_host=='192.168.168.21']`

P.S. you usually don't want to use `var` option of `debug` module to print Jinja statements, use `msg` instead.

Comment: Hmm, when I write `*[?ansible_host=='192.168.56.101']` I read it like `select every hash where ansible_host == 192.168.56.101`. It is wrong, obviously, but can you explain it a bit more? Or give a link to docs to learn it? Your solutions works, anyway.

Comment: Afaik [filters](http://jmespath.org/specification.html#filter-expressions) work only for lists, not hashes. So you make a list of all items within original hash, stop further projections with pipe and then work with this list applying required filters.